# Unable to Ping from VMWARE Linux Guest to Other VMs running but can ping Windows Guest to others

Tags: networking, vmware, vmware-workstation, network-adapter

I have setup few VMware machines. namely Windows 10/7/XP and linux Kali/CentOS/Metasploitable

I have tried seting up the Network Modes as following on all the machines one at a time
Host-only
Bridged
Each machine at one using same network mode on same network.
But I am always able to ping Windows --> Linux
[image: ping from windows to linux sucessfull]
 but never from linux --> Windows or other linux
[image: Ping from Linux to Windows all packets lost]
I have also disabled the host firewall, changed inbound outbound rules to allow File Printer sharing and Echo Request on IPv4.
[image: Firewall Disabled]
[image: The Firewall inbound rules for ECHO Request]
[image: The vmware network mode is bridged for both the machines and I have also tried Host only and Host network for both the VMs]

[image: Vvmware network prefrences]
[image: I am able to ping gateway from linux]
i can browse internet on linux but not ping other VMs.

What is the error here ? I have tried it setting same VM network for for the machines but not able to ping linux to windows.

Comment: "Host only" means exactly that: the network allows traffic to and from the host that is running VMware Workstation *only*, not to other VMs. You would have to setup the VMs with *Bridged* networking for them to behave like physical machines on your LAN and be able to PING each other.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a few phisical network adapters on your windows host, than you could try

- to Restore Defaults
- to connect all your machines to bridged network adapter which have connection to the Internet previously identifying the correct one.

[image]

I think, VMNet1 Type should be bridged. Better use your renamed VMNet2 for Host-only network. In case of using host-only network, one of VMs or Host could have a few network adapters (one of which is looking to the Internet) and could be configured as router to allow other VMs to connect to the Internet through it, but it is better to use NAT for this purpose, connecting all VMs to NAT.

Also don't forget to stop running all your VMs and reboot your Host before or after these manipulations.

Answer (score -2):

disable netqueue and network driver level

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you [edit] your answer and explain *how* to do the things you are suggesting, and *why* you are suggesting them? Thanks!